# How to get number of occurance and the field value from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

Table

```
ID Name 
1  abc
2  cde
3  xyz
4  abc
5  cde
6  cde
```

My expected result is

```
abc 2
cde 3
```

how will be the query ?

Comment: What is wrong in the question to down vote ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a `GROUP BY` statement:

```
SELECT name, count(*) cnt
FROM your_table
GROUP BY name;
```

As suggested by @jadarnel27, you can limit the results to only showing duplicates as follows:

```
SELECT name, count(*) cnt
FROM your_table
GROUP BY name
HAVING cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Additionally, you could add a `WHERE name IN ('abc', 'cde')` if OP's looking for that specific result.  Your query eds up with an `xyz  1` record in it =)

Comment: Ooh, ooh, or a `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` clause after the `GROUP BY` if he's only looking for results with duplicity!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name, count(*)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```